# Пригласить друга с соц.сети .Android

Tags: java, android, google-play

Вопрос следующий: каким образом я могу реализовать приглашение в приложение через ссылку в социальных сетях? Тобишь, в приложении я нажимаю " пригласить друга ", выбираю соц.сеть, отправяю другу. Друг переходит по этой ссылке, если у него приложение установленно - оно запускается, если нет - выводит в плей маркет.
Какие инструменты нужно для этого изучить? И , я так понял, нужно сперва в плей маркет приложение залить? Ибо куда будет отправляться ссылка, если у пользователя нет данного приложения.
Благодарю за ответы

Comment: По моему мнению, это `если у него приложение установленно - оно запускается, если нет - выводит в плей маркет` - невозможно (или очень сложно). Проще оставить 1 ссылку - для приложения в магазине, ведь если оно установлено, то пользователю останется только нажать на кнопку "Открыть"

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов это очень просто

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно научить ваше приложение обрабатывать открытие ссылок вашего особого вида. Их два вида, Deep link и Android App Links. Какие вам лучше подойдут вам самим придется решить, почитайте про них. Может оба вида будете использовать.

Ну а дальше вам остается только генерировать эту особую ссылку и передавать в send_action

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ использовать firebase dynamic links.
Как раз ваш вариант.
Там при создании ссылки учитывается много параметров. В том числе открыта ссылка, с android или ios или вообще с компьютера.

 Так же вы с помощью sdk  сможете перехватывать линки и открывать в вашем приложении

Второй вариант можно использовать Deep link, но это несколько сложнее, хотя на мой взгляд не сильно.

Но по сути  Firebase dynamic links это и есть красивая обвязка над Deep link